# Obtain PHP7.0 on Debian 7

Tags: debian, php

Is there still any possibility to install PHP7 on Debian Wheezy (7.11) ?

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
```

Commands

```
# apt-get install php7.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0'
```

Only PHP5 packages are available.

Comment: Dotdeb has it for Jessie...

Comment: Have you seen e.g. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-php-7-on-debian-linux-8-jessie-wheezy-using-apt-get/

Comment: Yeah, it was my first shot, but unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I haven't found any feasible solution for me (I was too lazy to compile from source) and I upgraded to Debian Jessie with the help of this article

https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html